# Exclude folders from recursion in recursive directory iterator php

Tags: php, directory-listing

I need to exclude all files and folders from a certain directories while doing the recursion. I have this code so far :

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($websiteRoot.$file["filepathfromroot"]));
     foreach ($it as $currentfile)
     {
      if (!$it->isDot()&&$it->isFile()&&!in_array($it->getSubPath(), $file["exclude-directories"])) {

        //do something
         }
     }
```

However this subpath will only match for children and and not files and sub directories off the children. i.e For a directory structure of Foo/bar/hello.php. If you add Foo to the exclude list hello.php would still come in the result.

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: Is it not because you work with the main object, and not the file representation it self? E.g. `$it->isDot()` should be `$currentFile->isDot()`

Comment: i changed it but the current file is a splfileinfo object which doesnt have a getsubpath function or isdot function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :

```
in_array($it->getSubPath(), $file["exclude-directories"])
```

By something like :

```
!in_array_beginning_with($it->getSubPath(), $file["exclude-directories"])
```

And you implement the function :

```
function in_array_beginning_with($path, $array) {
  foreach ($array as $begin) {
    if (strncmp($path, $begin, strlen($begin)) == 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

But that's not a very good way because you will recursivly get into useless directories even if they are very big and deep. In your case, I'll suggest you to do a old-school recursive function to read your directory :

```
<?php

function directory_reader($dir, array $ignore = array (), array $deeps = array ())
{
    array_push($deeps, $dir);
    $fulldir = implode("/", $deeps) . "/";
    if (is_dir($fulldir))
    {
        if (($dh = opendir($fulldir)) !== false)
        {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                $fullpath = $fulldir . $file;
                if (in_array($fullpath, $ignore)) {
                    continue ;
                }

                // do something with fullpath
                echo $fullpath . "<br/>";

                if (is_dir($fullpath) && (strcmp($file, '.') != 0) && (strcmp($file, '..') != 0))
                {
                    directory_reader($file, $ignore, $deeps);
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    array_pop($deeps);
}
```

If you try `directory_reader(".", array("aDirectoryToIngore"))`, it will not be read at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution.

```
$str_path = '/PATH/';

$cls_rii =  new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $str_path ),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

$ary_files = array();

foreach ( $cls_rii as $str_fullfilename => $cls_spl ) {
    
    if($cls_spl->isFile())
    {
        $ary_files[] = $str_fullfilename;
    }
    
}

$ary_files = array_combine(
    $ary_files,
    array_map( "filemtime", $ary_files )
);

arsort( $ary_files );

$str_latest_file = key( $ary_files );

echo "file:".$str_latest_file."\n";
echo "time:".$ary_files[key( $ary_files )];
```