# PHP Recursive Directory Iterator - ignore certain files.

Tags: php, iterator

I have a recursive directory iterator to select files from within a directory. SKIP_DOTS allows me to ignore the '.' and '..' elements, but I'd like to be able to also ignore '__MACOSX' directory and another other hidden files such as '.cache.php'

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$all_files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);
```

There are other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454114/exclude-folders-from-recursion-in-recursive-directory-iterator-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141468/how-to-exclude-file-types-from-directory-iterator-loop) but just wondered if there was a cleaner way?

I was hoping there was going to be something in [PHP Manual - FilesystemIterator SetFlags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants) but it seems not.

Comment: Why were you hoping for something built-in? Is it unreasonable to expect someone to write a few lines of code when they have special requirements? In Windows systems you often see special `desktop.ini` and `Thumbs.db` files, should there be a special flag for those too?

Comment: May be that will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454114/exclude-folders-from-recursion-in-recursive-directory-iterator-php

Comment: @Jon I see your point, but then why include 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS' if not to help out common use cases?

Comment: @Kiksy: A naive program that processes the dots entries would immediately go into infinite recursion, so pretty much *everyone* would want to filter them out. Not to mention that dots is a convention applicable to practically all filesystems supported on all platforms that PHP runs on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @Sven and the PHP Docs:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$filter = new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($iterator);

$all_files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter,RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Then extended [RecursiveFilterIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php)

```
class MyRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {

    public static $FILTERS = array(
        '__MACOSX',
    );

    public function accept() {
        return !in_array(
            $this->current()->getFilename(),
            self::$FILTERS,
            true
        );
    }

}
```

As per the comment [In the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php#103830)

Comment: This depends on flags `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` has set, here the code expects `parent::current()` to return a `SplFileInfo` object - but it can be a string as well. As an alternative one could work on the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` itself and use the `$this->getBasename()` (the filter decorates) or `$this->getFilename()`. Just adding. Taking care within the constructor to only accept `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` as `$iterator` can be helpful, too. I placed some code in a gist for linux hidden files: [`HiddenFilesAndFolderFilterIterator.php`](https://gist.github.com/hakre/11111534)

Answer (score 1):

Add a filter layer between RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator: Create a RecursiveFilterIterator and code the `accept()` function that returns true if you want the element to be in the result. Put the directory iterator into the filter iterator, put the filter iterator in the RecursiveIteratorIterator. Iterate.

There is no predefined SKIP constant for such special cases as "__MACOSX" directories.

Answer (score 1):

To filter other items, you can utilize `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`. This
is nice because with folders that hit the filter, the entire subpath is pruned.
Here is an example filtering a file and subfolder:

```
<?php

$f_filter = function ($o_info) {
   $s_file = $o_info->getFilename();
   if ($s_file == '.git') {
      return false;
   }
   if ($s_file == 'readme.md') {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
};

$o_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$o_filter = new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($o_dir, $f_filter);
$o_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($o_filter);

foreach ($o_iter as $o_info) {
   echo $o_info->getPathname(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator